# Calculate growth percentage between previous year and current year

Tags: mysql

I want to calculate the growth percentage over the previous year.

Table structure:

```
CustomerName | Sum_1415 | Sum_1516
```

I have tried this query:

```
select CustomerName, SUM(Sum_1415), SUM(Sum_1516), 
    round(sum(Sum_1516)-Sum(Sum_1415)/(select sum(Sum_1415) from dummy),2) as Percentage 
from dummy 
group by CustomerName 
order by Sum_1415 desc 
limit 15
```

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you are doing. Show some sample data, expected output and issue which you are facing with present query?

Comment: The subquery `(select sum(Sum_1415) from dummy)` isn't grouped by `CustomerName`, so it will be the total for all customers.

Comment: The table structure is as above. Sum_1415 contains 2014-2015 Revenue of customers and Sum_1516 contains revenue of same customers. We need to add the growth percentage column which needs to be calculated.

Comment: @Barmar: What changes are needed to be done here. Can u pls guide on the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the subquery `(select sum(Sum_1415) from dummy)` with just `sum(Sum_1415)`. Otherwise, you're calculating the ratio of the growth for each customer to the total of all revenues from the previous year, not the total for that customer.

You were also missing some parentheses inside the `ROUND` call, around the subtraction `sum(Sum_1516)-Sum(Sum_1415)`.

```
select CustomerName, SUM(Sum_1415) AS Sum_1415, SUM(Sum_1516) AS Sum_1516, 
    round((sum(Sum_1516)-Sum(Sum_1415))/SUM(Sum_1415),2) as Percentage 
from dummy 
group by CustomerName 
order by Sum_1415 desc 
limit 15
```

I would probably refactor this into a subquery so it's not necessary to keep repeating the `SUM` expressions.

```
SELECT CustomerName, Sum_1415, Sum_1516, ROUND((Sum_1516-Sum_1415)/Sum_1415, 2) AS Percentage
FROM (SELECT CustomerName, SUM(Sum_1415) AS Sum_1415, SUM(Sum_1516) AS Sum_1516
      FROM dummy
      GROUP BY CustomerName
      ORDER BY Sum_1516 DESC
      LIMIT 15) AS x
```

Comment: I have tried your query but the we aren't getting the required output.

Comment: Please update the question with sample input and the desired output. A sqlfiddle would be helpful, too.

Comment: Did you try it before I added the parentheses inside the `ROUND` call? You had the operator precedence wrong, so it wasn't dividing the difference by the previous year.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your query helped. Getting the desired output.